# ArcScene transparency per feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, transparency-opacity

I am working with some data that needs to be visualized in different transparencies levels.
I know how to do it in ArcMap: Symobology --> Advanced --> Transparency.
Now I am working a 3D project and I want to do the same only in ArcScene, so you can look through the surface. I tried to do it just like in ArcMap but it does not work.

Anyone has an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The transparency option is available in ArcScene, 3D analyst license is required.

> Transparency can be used for any symbolization type, but it is especially useful for drawing raster layers with other layers on your map. Adding transparency to the top layers allows you to see them while still viewing underlying layers. You can use either a specific percentage value or an interactive slider to adjust the transparency of a layer inside either ArcGlobe or ArcScene.

[image]

> To review and set transparency using the Display tab of the Layer Properties dialog box, follow the steps below:
>
> In the table of contents, right-click the layer and click Properties.
> Click the Display tab.
> Type a value in the Transparency box to specify the transparency level for this layer.
> A 0 value indicates no transparency, but values greater than 90 mean the layer generally won't draw at all.
> Click OK.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But with this you make a layer transparant. What I want to do is different transparencies in one layer. So for example the layer exists of four polygons. I want three polygons a transparency of 30% and one a transparency of 80%.

Comment: @NoNai add another layer for the same feature class, with a definition query that only shows that polygon (or doesn't show the polygon for the other layer) and then apply the different transparency to each layer